# How to add users to my contacts in Quickblox same as skype in android

Tags: android, quickblox-android

I wanted to list only the contacts that I add. For now, what I am getting is all the contacts who signup in Quickblox.

I don't want all the users of Quickblox. I want to display only the contacts/users I added. And need to send a kind of request to the contact/user I want to add. After accepting only it should add into my user list. Is this possible using Quickblox?